# Bootstrap Grid System Alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, grid, alignment, width

I'm trying to create a profile page using the Bootstraps grid system, It would work perfectly but unfortunately my page has another responsive dynamic feature - a menu appears on the left hand side at larger resolutions.

This menu is effecting the columns as the grid thinks it's not being pushed to the right and they are sprawling off the page! When the menu moves to the top at smaller resolutions Bootstrap does its thing properly. See http://hertfordhotshots.weebly.com/honors.html and play with the widths to see my issue.

Is there anything I can do to make bootstrap give me the desired effect and keep the menu on the left?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this works... at the html snipe inside class="team"...
eliminate class="container" and class="row"...instead that, add class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 " in both divs...

```
    <section class="team">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">//class="container
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">//class="row"
         <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h6 class="description">CURRENT TEAM</h6>
            <div class="row pt-md">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile">
               <div class="img-box">
                 <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" class="img-responsive">
                <ul class="text-center">
                   <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li></a>
                   <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
                   <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
                </ul>
              </div>
          <h1>Joe McClemont</h1>
          <h2>Co-founder/ Midfielder</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
       ...
   ...
   ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```